# how to protect a send_file action with cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, sendfile, x-sendfile

I can't seem to approve authorization for the `web_videos_display` action. I can make it work by using the `skip_authorize_resource` but then any user can access the URL for the file by knowing the `:id`. I need to require access to the `asset` to "see" the file.

thank you for looking into this.

#### assets_controller.rb

```
...
class AssetsController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource :team
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :team

  # skip_authorize_resource :only => [:web_videos_display, ...]
  # skip_authorize_resource :team, :only => [:web_videos_display, ...]
  ...
  def web_videos_display
    # @asset = Asset.find(params[:id]) #loaded by cancan
    @file = "#{Rails.root}#{@asset.webVideos.last.file}"
    send_file @file, :disposition => 'inline', :x_sendfile=>true
  end
  ...
```

#### routes.rb

```
  resources :teams, :path => '', :except => [:index] do
  ...
    resources :assets, :path => '' do
      ...
      get 'web_videos_display'
      ...
    end
  end
```

#### show.html.erb

```
...
<%= team_asset_web_videos_display_path(@team, @asset, :id => @asset.id, :team_id => @team.id) %>
...
```

#### ability.rb

```
...
can :read, Team, :memberships => {:id => user.membership_ids}
can :manage, Asset, :team => { :id => user.team_ids }
can :web_videos_display, Asset, :team => { :id => user.team_ids }
...
```

---

## update in response to @ryanb comment

that returns

```
1.9.2p318 :006 > ability.can?(:web_videos_display, asset)
  Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
 => true
```

but

in development mode it still returns

```
Started GET "/video-pros/test-1/web_videos_display?id=10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-09 16:40:19 -0800
  Processing by AssetsController#web_videos_display as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"10", "team_id"=>"video-pros", "asset_id"=>"test-1"}
  Team Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."slug" = 'video-pros' LIMIT 1
  Team Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."admin_user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "teams".* FROM "teams" WHERE "teams"."slug" = 'video-pros' LIMIT 1
Access denied on show #<Team id: 1, name: "Video Pros", email: nil, phone: nil, website: nil, slug: "video-pros", admin_user_id: 1, created_at: "2012-11-06 22:43:11", updated_at: "2012-11-06 22:43:11", payment_received: nil>
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 73ms>
```

thanks Ryan

Answer (score 1):

`send_file` shouldn't make a difference since the authorization happens in a before_filter before the action gets triggered. As far as I can tell it looks correct so there may be something else going on. Have you tried going through this [debugging](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Debugging-Abilities) page? What happens if you mimic what the controller authorization is doing in the console?

```
user = User.first # fetch any user you want to test abilities on
team = Team.first # any model you want to test against
asset = team.assets.first
ability = Ability.new(user)
ability.can?(:show, team) # see if it allows access
ability.can?(:web_videos_display, asset) # see if it allows access
```

*updated `:read` to `:show` action for team*

Comment: i updated the original with the output of the console and terminal

Comment: It appears it is denying access to the parent Team record. Make sure that works in the console too: `ability.can?(:show, team)`

Comment: To clarify, the `load_and_authorize_resource :team` line is going to add a before filter to authorize the parent record. If you don't want that you can do `load_resource :team` instead.